# Tag a process with a string

Tags: windows, process, sysinternals

I am trying to reproduce Process Exporer's feature to tag a process running on the current machine with a Comment (Please see the Comment section in the Process properties in Process Explorer).

I couldn't find any way to do it with managed code, had a try with wmic utility but I wasn't able to find a way to set a property to an existing process.

Also, searching the web returns some pretty vague responses since all the search terms are so general..

Alex.

P.S I am using C# for the project but I am opened to use unmanaged code if that's what it takes :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't you think that this is internal feature of Process Explorer? They might store with process info some string comment. In case of .net you will have `Process` object, just add a `Dictionary<Process, string>` and store comments there

Comment: I would recommend creating a wrapper class for this rather than keeping a `Dictionary` in sync, but this is nonetheless workable.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.  If you close and reopen Process Explorer after setting such a tag, is it still there?

Comment: @harpo: i have no idea. either it is not that hard to store that data in file

Comment: @Adam Robinson agree, but i suggested Dictionary as simpler example

Comment: I don't know if it's an internal feature. I tried closing and reopening process explorer. Deleted the temp files that process explorer creates in its folder and monitored registry for changes : nothing there. I assumed may be a Windows field that clould be acessed in some way.